# sane, can't find my scanner (permission problem) even if I added udev rules unless i use sudo

Tags: sudo, udev, scanner, sane, canon

My AIO Printer/Scanner is Canon E400 but I can't find my scanner as a normal user, only with sudo & scan is also work with sudo

```
~ cincinmasukmangkok@orangepizero
< sane-find-scanner                                                                                                       <<<

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 008:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 005:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 007:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04a9/0x177a at 004:007: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 006:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.

~ cincinmasukmangkok@orangepizero
> scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).

~ cincinmasukmangkok@orangepizero
< sudo sane-find-scanner                                                                                                  <<< [sudo] password for cincinmasukmangkok:

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x177a [E400 series]) at libusb:004:007
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

~ cincinmasukmangkok@orangepizero
< sudo scanimage --format=png > test.png                                                                                  <<<

~ cincinmasukmangkok@orangepizero 33s
>
```

I also added this to /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules but it still doesn't work

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="177a", MODE="0664", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Comment: Is `cincinmasukmangkok` in the `scanner` group?

Comment: @DanielFarrell yes, it is

Comment: and it's in the output of `groups` in your current shell?  Shells and other processes won't pick up the group changes until you create a new session, so ensure you're not in a session older than your addition to the `scanner` group.

Comment: @DanielFarrell groups output is `cincinmasukmangkok tty disk dialout sudo audio video plugdev games users systemd-journal input netdev ssh scanner` I even rebooted before and still not detecting

Comment: just making sure, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by adding this line to `/lib/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="177a", MODE="0666"`

Answer (score 0):

I added the account to `scanner`, `lp`, `saned`. But that alone did not help. I did not have any of those rules files so my solution was `sudo chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb`. Then you can check with `sane-find-scanner` to see if you find it with the normal user account.

I then added/created the `rc.local` file with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb
exit 0
```

Then I set `sudo chmod +x rc.local`.